# How to get access to Chart instance related to current tooltip callback in Chart.js

Tags: chart.js

I am trying to display percentage value inside doughnut chart. To my feature work properly i need to have access to chart instance inside callback. I don't know how to do that?

I handled that using **Chart.pluginService beforeDraw event** but it doesn't work as I expected.

Is there any way to move code from beforeDraw event inside tooltip callback ?

This is my code

```
tooltips: {
    callbacks: {
    label: function (tooltipItem, data) {

        var precentage = dataFromDoughnutChart;

        localStorage.setItem("per", precentage.toString());

        return precentage + "%";
    }
}
}

Chart.pluginService.register({

        beforeDraw: function (chart) {

            var value = "";
            var x = localStorage.getItem("per");

            if (x != null)
                value = x + "%";

            var width = chart.chart.width,
                height = chart.chart.height,
                ctx = chart.chart.ctx;

            ctx.restore();
            var fontSize = (height / 100).toFixed(2);
            ctx.font = fontSize + "em sans-serif";
            ctx.textBaseline = "middle";

            var text = value,
                textX = Math.round((width - ctx.measureText(text).width) / 2),
                textY = height / 2;

            ctx.fillText(text, textX, textY);
            ctx.save();
        },
        afterEvent: function (chart, event) {

            if (event.type == "mouseout") {

                localStorage.removeItem("per");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you explain what your trying to do in more detail?  Are you trying to show the percentage in the middle when a user rolls over a section a slice of the doughnut?  Also, can you explain what incorrect behavior you are getting with your approach?  I have done a similar thing before but don't want to share until I understand what you are after.

Comment: That is right, I am trying to achieve exactly that.
Incorrect behavior is that beforeDraw event is invoked several times. I don't have just only one doughnut chart on the page and when I move cursor fast from one doughnut chart slice to second chart both charts are displaying the same values in the middle of chart.
I am trying to do something based on [link]https://jsfiddle.net/cmyker/ooxdL2vj/
and fill middle chart area data from tooltip callback.
Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best approach to solving your problem is to actually use [custom tooltips](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#advanced-usage-external-tooltips) instead of attempting a plugin.  Here is a working solution that I modified from one of the chart.js sample pages in their repo.

First define a container for the custom tooltip in yout HTML.

```
<div id="chartjs-tooltip"></div>
```

Then use the below custom tooltip function.  You might have to tweak the `centerX` calculation for your needs.  This function basically calculates the percentage value of the currently active slice (by dividing the datapoint by the total value of datapoints), places it in the custom tooltip div, and positions the div in the center of the doughnut.

```
Chart.defaults.global.tooltips.custom = function(tooltip) {
  // Tooltip Element
  var tooltipEl = document.getElementById('chartjs-tooltip');

  // Hide if no tooltip
  if (tooltip.opacity === 0) {
    tooltipEl.style.opacity = 0;
    return;
  }

  // Set Text
  if (tooltip.body) {
    var total = 0;

    // get the value of the datapoint
    var value = this._data.datasets[tooltip.dataPoints[0].datasetIndex].data[tooltip.dataPoints[0].index].toLocaleString();

    // calculate value of all datapoints
    this._data.datasets[tooltip.dataPoints[0].datasetIndex].data.forEach(function(e) {
      total += e;
    });

    // calculate percentage and set tooltip value
    tooltipEl.innerHTML = '<h1>' + (value / total * 100) + '%</h1>';
  }

  // calculate position of tooltip
  var centerX = (this._chartInstance.chartArea.left + this._chartInstance.chartArea.right) / 2;
  var centerY = ((this._chartInstance.chartArea.top + this._chartInstance.chartArea.bottom) / 2);

  // Display, position, and set styles for font
  tooltipEl.style.opacity = 1;
  tooltipEl.style.left = centerX + 'px';
  tooltipEl.style.top = centerY + 'px';
  tooltipEl.style.fontFamily = tooltip._fontFamily;
  tooltipEl.style.fontSize = tooltip.fontSize;
  tooltipEl.style.fontStyle = tooltip._fontStyle;
  tooltipEl.style.padding = tooltip.yPadding + 'px ' + tooltip.xPadding + 'px';
};
```

Here is the full end-to-end working example via codepen:

[Chart.js Doughnut Center Percentage](http://codepen.io/jordanwillis/pen/vxNRmW/)

Comment: That was helpfull. I need to modify your source code but I have used your idea. Thanks